# Getting ODP.NET Managed Driver to work with ADO.NET TableAdapters

Tags: oracle, ado.net, odp.net, tableadapter

I've got a WCF service (.NET Framework 4) that uses Table Adapters (xsd) and `System.Data.OracleClient` as a dependency. I'm trying to switch to the new `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`.

I've installed the `ODP.NET Managed Driver` from NuGet. Everything went fine, it installed correctly as a reference.

I've put the following in the `app.config` file:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="ODP.NET Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and changed the providerName attribute for the ConnectionString to `providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"`

Then I double click on the Table Adapter (the `xsd` file) and right click on the Table Adapter I want to change and click on `Properties`. Then I get this dialog up:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J543Rqw.png]

*Note: The `ConnectionString` has been removed from the screenshot*

When I change the value of `Provider` to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` I get the following error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kuNg2J0.png]

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use VS designers and wizards for Tableadapters or Entity Framework, you must install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (ODT). Note that this does not support VS Express Edition. In your specific case, this install will update the machine config so that ODP.NET is registered as a factory provider.

You can download ODT here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

As a side note - please note that the Nuget package hosted on nuget.org was not put there by Oracle. If you want an official download you should get it from oracle.com.